# Парсинг прокси с сайта через WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, парсер

Нужно спарсить прокси с одного сайта. Там стоит похоже защита от DDOS поэтому обычными методами не работает. Получается получить список только через WebBrowser1.

Вопрос: Как после получения списка прокси в WebBrowser1 сохранить их в txt на рабочий стол?

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=get%20text%20from%20twebbrowser%20delphi&es_th=1

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить доступ к тексту с помощью, в текущем примере HTML текст записывается в переменную HtmlText, дальше если нужно - парсим его.

```
var
  Doc: IHtmlDocument2;
  HtmlText: String;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHtmlDocument2;
  HtmlText := Doc.body.innerHTML;
end;
```

PS: пример взят с [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13970551/2546083)
Кстати если браузер загружает контент, тогда его можно вытащить и с помощью idHttp, нужно просто правильно сформировать заголовок. Для просмотра что отправляется на сервер можно воспользоваться утилитой мониторинга трафика [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)